# Stange issue with session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

I have something strange going on with our session state.
Our ASP.NET C# application has a session timeout of 10 min, but it seems to be losing session state when redirecting between pages.

So, we set out session value, and redirect to the next step,

```
        Session["temp"] = "somevalue";
        Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```

At the top of page2, we check the session value, and if it's not there, redirect back to the start (the code below is the first on `Page_Load`):

```
        if (Session["temp"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("start.aspx");
        }
```

The issue is it keeps on doing this redirect, even though the session should not have timed out.

I have checked the config file, and it has a machinekey, as I have been informed that this can sometimes causes issues if it's not there.

Is there something else that could be causing us to lose the session?

Comment: <system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" /> Can you show us what you have set here? Feel free to check http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/03/24/sessionstate.html for info.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how your session's configured, cookie problems can cause you to lose session. As can switching domains / switching between http and https.

And as an aside, if you're connecting over a mobile connection, all sorts of horrible things can happen to your cookies...

Answer (score 1):

Disabled Coockies may be issue. You can also create brand new application (with default web.config without any change) with single page and test it. This will tell you whether the problem is application specific or server specific.

Answer (score 0):

try to add to `system.webServer -> modules` section in web.config next lines:

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
```

Comment: The site is running on IIS6 (not our choice), so does this just go in httpmodules?